# Remove duplicate items inside multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have an array which contains multiple of the same data:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(11) "43000173601"
    ["data"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(5) "52874"
        ["name"]=>
        string(3) "x70"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(5) "52874"
        ["name"]=>
        string(3) "x70"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(11) "43000173602"
    ["data"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(5) "52874"
        ["name"]=>
        string(3) "x70"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried using `array_unique()` to remove these entries, but receive this error:

> Array to string conversion

The outer arrays contain route ID's, some busses may have 2 different routes so in this case, they can stay however, I just want to remove the dupe entries inside the 1 route:

```
[0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(11) "43000173601"
    ["data"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(5) "52874"
        ["name"]=>
        string(3) "x70"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(5) "52874"
        ["name"]=>
        string(3) "x70"
      }
    }
```

Comment: And what do you want from us?

Comment: To help me remove the duplicate entries inside the routes, please @u_mulder

Comment: Always the lowest key that should remain?

Comment: this comment in the docs might help: http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-unique.php#97285

Comment: When posting questions it's best to post arrays made by `var_export` and not `print_r`  the ones from var export are usable in code, the ones from print_r are human readable, so to use it one has to fix it first, where as var export can just be pasted and worked with.  I'd help you but I'm to lazy to fix it.  One day I will make a print_r converter ...

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix you can find on StackOverflow such function :) But it works not good

Comment: I will write a lexer for it that will work flawlessly,  [Lexers I've Made](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/tree/master/Lexers)  just saying.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I use http://print-r-converter-199219.appspot.com if its tidy (source: https://github.com/lcherone/print_r-converter) ;p

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - they used `var_dump`.  Sorry I put the wrong one ^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code can be something like this:

```
$new_array = [];
foreach ($your_array as $item) {
    if (!isset($new_array[$item['id']])) {
        // item id is not in `new_array` - add `item`
        $new_array[$item['id']] = $item;
    } else {
        // item id already presents - add `data` item to it
        $new_array[$item['id']]['data'][] = $item['data'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This did work but I found an easier way to do it, but I will mark this since it does work!

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_column to make the array associative. That will remove any duplicates.
Array_values will then remove the associative and make it normal indexed array again.
Rsort makes sure you get the lowest key as the result array.

```
rsort($arr);
$arr = array_values(array_column($arr, Null, "id"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by doing this:

```
$stripped = [];
foreach($arr as $single) {
    $stripped[] = ['id' => $single['id'], 'data' => array_unique($single['data'])];
}
```

Since the duplicates existed inside the inner arrays, not the outer array, I had to use `array_unique()` on the inner arrays.